# Visual Studio App Center - Agente Build

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, mobile-center, visual-studio-app-center

When I automatically build my Xamarin Forms applications (Android and iOS) on the Visual Studio App Center platform, the components are not automatically downloaded as NuGet packages. When a reference error is not found and executed. How to solve this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [Build Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile-center/build/ios/first-build/xamarin/) of Moblie Center, Xamarin component is not supported in its **Build** feature. They advise user using NuGet packages instead. Or contact them in the internal support chat in Mobile Center.

> **Supported versions and requirements**
>
> Mobile Center has no support for Components from the Xamarin Component Store and we advise using NuGet packages whenever they are available. If you are using a Component which cannot be replaced, please reach out to us: Click on the blue bubble on the bottom right corner once you're logged in to Mobile Center and share your feedback with us.